# Selenium - PHP error - Finding text not contained in an tag

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I find elements either by their ID or tag or etc. But my element is in a body tag with no tags at all, how can I find this? I know it is in the body tag but there are other elements too! The "text I want to find" is a php error displayed and I am hoping to catch that. I usually go writing `WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.??);`  I cant proceed because I am uncertain what to do.

Sample HTML doc

```
<head></head>

<body>

Text I want to find

<div>xx</div>
<div>yy</div>

</body>
```

The reason for the java tag is, I am using Java to write my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation I'd have used "context item expression" i.e. a `.`(dot) operator. So if I write an Xpath like this:

```
//div[contains(.,'Text To Be Searched')]
```

Then it will find all div elements which contain text `Text To Be Searched`. For you my answer would be

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[contains(.,'Text I want to find')]"));
```

Comment: I like that but what if I want text in body tag not contained in any tag? Cuz the php error can be of ANY type and the Text to be searched may vary

Comment: `//*[contains(.,'Text I want to find')]` - It will find all web elements which has text 'Text I want to find'.

Comment: That Text I want to find can vary.

Answer (score 0):

You should add that text inside p tag and then you can write :

```
WebElement x = driver.getElementByTag('p');
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the webpage. I haven't written the code. It is actually an error popping up, saying "::$cardPackage in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/corporate/verify.php on line 63"/